Name of kids TV show where dog was the messiah
This was a kids show which would have been on TVO (TV Ontario) around twenty years ago. It was a live action show, I think from Britain or Australia, as I recall them having funny accents.
Now then, in this show:

There were Bad Aliens that came to Earth
You know they were bad, because they did bad things
One of these things was spraying goop on objects, then eating them (e.g. furniture)
To help humanity, the Good Aliens came to Earth
The good aliens brought with them Good Alien Technology™
One of these technologies was a pill that would cause any fluid vessel to magically refill 500 times (this will be very important)
However, they couldn't defeat the Bad Aliens on their own, they needed the help of the Messiah
The problem was, they didn't know who the Messiah was
There was a Magic Artifact™ that would reveal who was the Messiah when placed on their head
The Magic Artifact™ turned out to be a punch bowl
Unfortunately, this punch bowl had had a magic 500 refill pill put it in
Much pouring of punch ensued
In the end, the Messiah turned out to be the dog


The Australian The Miraculous Mellops from 1991:

The first season centred on the "Search for the Grand Baby" plot. An alien race of children exist on the moon, known as Moonlings. Their leader, The Grand Baby, is fast approaching the end of his life, and without an heir, it is decided that a great power will be sent to Earth to choose a new leader for the people there. The power itself, consisting of all the psychic and magical abilities that the Grand Baby possessed, arrived on Earth but hit the Mellops' crystal punchbowl, "splitting" around the house, hitting several household items.

There are tablets that keep that bowl full of punch, and the aliens' leader (The "Grand Baby") turns out to be the family dog, Ajax. Here are the opening credits:




That's it! I seem to have melded the two seasons together in my head.
